# Django Advanced Tutorial: Error when trying run server or migrate app after successfully installing own package

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-apps

I'm following the Advanced Django Tutorial and have managed to package my polls app into another directory outside of mysite directory. I run 
`pip install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz` inside the directory which my django-polls app is at and manage to successfully install it. However, when I try to run `python manage.py runserver` inside the **`mysite`** directory I get the following message on my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/*USER*/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/*USER*/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/*USER*/django/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/*USER*/django/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/*USER*/django/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/Users/*USER*/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polls.apps'
```

I tried running `python manage.py migrate` and get the same message. Could someone explain what's happening here? I'm running the latest version of Django.

UPDATE: these are the apps installed on my `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I tried using

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'polls', ...
```

but that just gives another error, `No module named 'polls.urls'`

EDIT 2: As requested below is my directory schema, I moved the `django-polls` and `mysite` folders into a parent directory `django-tutorial`. However, when running the command `python manage.py runserver` it replied: `/usr/bin/python: No module named django` I then reinstalled Django using `pip` and reinstalled the `django-polls` module. That seemed to fix the issue. I can now run the `python manage.py runserver` command and get my project running as before. I have no idea Django was removed from the path put managed to get it back running. Thank you all for the help!

```
django-tutorial
├── django-polls
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── MANIFEST.in
│   ├── README.rst
│   ├── dist
│   │   └── django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
│   ├── django_polls.egg-info
│   │   ├── PKG-INFO
│   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   └── top_level.txt
│   ├── docs
│   ├── polls
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── apps.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── tests.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── polls
│   │   │       ├── images
│   │   │       │   └── background.gif
│   │   │       └── style.css
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── polls
│   │   │       ├── detail.html
│   │   │       ├── index.html
│   │   │       └── results.html
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── setup.py
└── mysite
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── django-polls
    │   └── setup.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── mysite
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── polls
    │   └── views.py
    └── templates
        └── admin
            └── base_site.html
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yellow background may look nice, but it is intended for the cites, please remove this highlighting and you are fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your settings.py look like? have you added polls into your INSTALLED_APPS?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'polls',
....
]
```

Comment: I've got:

` INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]`

Comment: Can you share your directories schema? like from the root of the app.